# Reading from CSV file only returns one line in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, csv

I am trying to input a csv file into a Visual Basic Data Grid. But each time I try to call an entry it only reads the first Line, The goal is to read a random line and input the name into the Column.

The CSV File:

```
Noah,
Liam,
Mason,
Jacob,
William,
Ethan,
James,
Alexander,
Michael,
Benjamin,
Elijah,
Daniel,
Aiden,
Logan,
Matthew,
Lucas,
Jackson,
David,
Oliver,
Jayden,
Joseph,
Gabriel,
Samuel,
Carter,
Anthony,
John,
Dylan,
Luke,
Henry,
Andrew,
Isaac,
Christopher,
Joshua,
Wyatt,
Sebastian,
Owen,
Caleb,
Nathan,
Ryan,
Jack,
Hunter,
Levi,
Christian,
Jaxon,
Julian,
Landon,
Grayson,
Jonathan,
Isaiah,
Charles,
Thomas,
Aaron,
Eli,
Connor,
Jeremiah,
Cameron,
Josiah,
Adrian,
Colton,
Jordan,
Brayden,
Nicholas,
Robert,
Angel,
Hudson,
Lincoln,
Evan,
Dominic,
Austin,
Gavin,
Nolan,
Parker,
Adam,
Chase,
Jace,
Ian,
Cooper,
Easton,
Kevin,
Jose,
Tyler,
Brandon,
Asher,
Jaxson,
Mateo,
Jason,
Ayden,
Zachary,
Carson,
Xavier,
Leo,
Ezra,
Bentley,
Sawyer,
Kayden,
Blake,
Nathaniel,
Ryder,
Theodore,
Elias,
Tristan,
Roman,
Leonardo,
Camden,
Brody,
Luis,
Miles,
Micah,
Vincent,
Justin,
Greyson,
Declan,
Maxwell,
Juan,
Cole,
```

The Code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' Initialize the random-number generator
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()

    For ix As Integer = 1 To 115

        Dim intValue As Integer = CInt(Int((5000 * Rnd()) + 1))
        Dim intRandomNumber As Integer
        Dim randomName As String = 0

        intRandomNumber = (100 * Rnd())
        Dim dat(230) As String 'This array holds each item from csv ile
        Dim num As Integer = 0
        Dim c, p, z As Integer
        Dim firstNames(115) As String
        Dim blankSpace(115) As Integer
        Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("firstNames.txt")
            MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
            Dim currentRow As String()

            'This section reads the text file into one array dat()
            While Not MyReader.EndOfData
                Try
                    currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                    For Each currentField In currentRow
                        num = num + 1
                        dat(num) = currentField
                    Next
                    'error reporting
                Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                    MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & "is not valid and will be skipped.")
                End Try
            End While
            p = 0
            For c = 1 To num Step 2
                p = p + 1
                firstNames(p) = dat(c)
            Next
        End Using
        For c = 1 To p
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(Format(ix, "00000"), firstNames(c), "", "", "", intValue)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect your code is throwing an exception before it repeats the loop. Is anything displayed in the Visual Studio Output window while you read the file?

Comment: Also, `String.Split` is not a good function for parsing a CSV file because it can't handle commas embedded in enquoted-strings, for example.

Comment: Your code is re-opening the file every time - that's part of the problem too.

Comment: You are splitting on the comma in each line read (assuming you are able to read each line), there's nothing after the comma, perhaps that's where the error is thrown

Answer (score 0):

The following method will return a specified number of random lines from a file:

```
'Random number generator.
Private rng As New Random

Private Function GetRandomLines(filePath As String, lineCount As Integer) As String()
    Return IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath).
                   OrderBy(Function(s) rng.NextDouble()).
                   Take(lineCount).
                   ToArray()

End Function
```

You can call that method and then loop through the results, splitting and loading.  If you only want one line rather than multiple then you can just call `First` or `FirstOrDefault` and return a `String` instead of an array.

With regards to splitting the data, it would be preferable to use a `TextFieldParser` if it might contain quoted field values that contain commas.  The problem with that is that you would have to split every line before you could know how many there are, which means redundant work.

Comment: Not good to order by random. It's possible to put your program into a state where the sort doesn't complete.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, I've never heard such a thing. Can you describe how?

Comment: What happens is .Net will have to call `rng.NextDouble()` more than once for the same value during an OrderBy(), as it compares that value with other items in the sequence. One time the result may be higher, pushing the item back in the sequence. Another time it may be lower, pushing it forward. With bad luck, it's possible for the function to never finish, or at least take much longer than it should.

Comment: Better to first `.Select()` an anonymous type with a random key for one property and original value for the other (or possibly a Tuple in VS2017), `OrderBy()` based on the result of the Select(). Then `Select()` again back to the original, in this case _after_ the `Take()` call to save some work. Also better to avoid the `ToArray()` call and just return `IEnumerable(Of String)`.

Comment: I just did a bit of reading and found similar information.  Not something I'd considered but, while unlikely to occur, clearly a potential issue.  Thanks.